# How to Merge Class with manually made Class.GeneratedCode.cs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

In my case, I making an item Template Project that one of the classes in the template Inherit `UserControl`. in addition I create manually `SameClassName.GeneratedCode.cs` but after I implement the New item I see both of the classes :

```
MyClass.cs  
- MyClass.Designer.cs
MyClass.GeneratedCode.cs
```

How can i merge them to :

```
MyClass.cs    
- MyClass.Designer.cs
- MyClass.GeneratedCode.cs
```

tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually change the `csproj` file.

Add the following tag to the `Compile` item of your file:

```
<Compile Include="MyClass.GeneratedCode.cs">
    <DependentUpon>MyClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: i need something automatic for been added as i create the item .. is it possible?

Comment: @LeonBarkan, AFAIK there is no built-in way for this. Maybe you could search the Visual Studio Marketplace for some extension, but this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: there is an extension for that but still, I creating item template so is not an option